# Cloud Core Data storage multiple users

Tags: core-data

Is it any Cloud Core Data storage engines? I very like how Core Data works, but Core Data is limited to local-only usage or via iCloud (it it can be used only on 1 iTunes account).

Any service host Core Data storages that can be shared accross multiple users or only way is it to use 3rd party bases (like Firebase + JSONSync + Core Data)? My question is only about Core Data native engines, not JSON/Firebase etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it available through `CKShare`. I recommend to check that video [WWDC 2016 - What's New with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/)